# Celery Results Backend HTML & JSON

Tags: python, json, django, celery, django-celery

The application I am working on requests content from static HTML pages and API endpoints and needs to support both content types in a result backend.

Is there a way to work with both HTML and JSON in a Celery Results Backend? I have tried setting `CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['text/plain', 'application/json']` and it throws error `is not JSON serializable` on all HTML results.

Comment: have you tried CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json','html']?

Comment: html is not a valid content type and using `['application/json','text/html']` together as a noted in the original message does not work. Updating question with error message.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution. Decode the HTML to UTF-8 and it will be in a JSON serializable format and the Celery Results Backend will accept the data.

```
@task
def request(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.content.decode('utf-8')
```